# Azure CI/CD pipeline for Angular 8 APP using Azure Deployment Groups

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, continuous-integration, virtual-machine

I have “.Net Core Web Api” and “Angular 8” projects. I am manually deploying these two application on Azure Virtual Machine. 
Now I want to use Azure CI/CD pipeline process and deployed above application on IIS present on above Azure Virtual Machine.
Can I achieve above tasks by using Azure Deployment Groups? I am not able to find proper solutions on internet.
Any help will be really appreciated.

I have this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops but no use.

Comment: Just want to confirm if you can deploy angular app to azure VM successfully by following answer? If not or has any confusing about it, free to comment below:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I achieve above tasks by using Azure Deployment Groups?

Of course sure. `Azure virtual machine` just the VM which hosted by Azure, there's no more difference with the normal VM.

---

To deploy application to Azure VMs through IIS tasks and azure devops deployment group, you must pay attention to below 2 **prerequisites**:

**1)** As normal, VM is a separated machine. In order to combine them into Azure Devops and use them with CI/CD, to be precise, let the `Deployment group` manage to these virtual machine, you need to run script to register these VMs to VSTS deployment group.

**2)** Also, to deploy application to VMs via IIS, you need also ensure that these VMs web servers configured with IIS.

Above 2 is what mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) you shared.

---

Our lab published a blog which describe the very detailed steps on how to [Deploying to Azure VM using Deployment Groups](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/#exercise-1-creating-deployment-groups-and-configuring-release). You can follow it to continue your configuration in VSTS pipeline.

Since it is very detailed, I would only point some key to you:

- **1** To configure `Deployment Group agent` on each of the virtual machines, firstly, please use `Azure Resource Group Deployment` task with Configure `virtual machine deployment options` **action** and **enable prerequisites** as `Configure with Deployment Group agent`:

[image]

- **2** For the configuration of IIS manage and deploy task, including `physical path` and etc, you can follow [this(just ignore its task of *start*)](https://www.getlatestversion.it/2019/04/27/deploy-a-new-iis-web-site-with-azure-devops-pipelines/) to finish your configuration.

**Note:**

Here you must add 2 phases since `Azure Resource Group Deployment` task need run with **agent job**, and `IIS web app manage/deploy` task run with **deployment group job**

[image]

---

These are the basic steps which could help you achieve what you want.